# Fetching the values from db before searching

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

In this below code when i execute it .It shows all the values from the database and when i search it is searching .But my expected result is when i execute it should not display data from the database and only when i search it should display the result.

Controller search1_site.php

```
<?php
class Search1_site extends ci_controller
{
    function index()
    {
        $data            = array();
        $keyword         = $this->input->post('keyword');
        $data['results'] = $this->search1_model->search($keyword);
        $this->load->view('result_view', $data);
    }
}
?>
```

model search_model.php

```
<?php
class Search_model extends CI_Model
{
    function search($keyword)
    {
        $this->db->like('course_code', $keyword);
        $query = $this->db->get('coursemaster');
        return $query->result();
    }
}
?>
```

view result_view.php

```
<form action="<?php echo site_url('search1_site/index');?>" method = "post">
<input type="text" name = "keyword" />
<input type="submit" id="opn" value = "Search"  />
</form>

<table>
<tr>
<th>course_code</th>
<th>course name</th>
</tr>
<?php
foreach ($results as $row) {
?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $row->course_code;?></td>
<td><?php echo $row->course_name;?></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
?> 
</table>
```

Comment: I did really look at your code that good, but in general, you want the database to do the searching, databases are way faster than php&arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In controller :

```
class Search1_site extends ci_controller
{
    function index()
    {
        $data            = array();
        $keyword         = $this->input->post('keyword');
        if($keyword!=""){
            $data['results'] = $this->search1_model->search($keyword);
        }
        $this->load->view('result_view', $data);
    }
}
```

in view :

```
<?php
if($results){
foreach ($results as $row) {
?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $row->course_code;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row->course_name;?></td>
</tr>
<?php
} 
}else{
   //Display somthing
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

When your page loads the keyword in the following line in your controller is going blank and its searching all the records as your query might be like %%.

```
$keyword    =   $this->input->post('keyword');
```

First check if $keyword is not blank. If its not blank then search the data.

Comment: it is searching my expectected result when i execute it should display textbox and submit button and not to display db results @Rahul Tailwal

Comment: Yes i understand it. As you are not posting any values as page loads then the $this->input->post('keyword') goes blank. and your search query gets all the records as your query is select * from table where column like '%$keyword%'. and u can see $keyword is blank. So just put condition in controller to check if keyword is posted or not.

Comment: I tried to give you logic so that you can code yourself. but i think you just want others to code for you.

Comment: I got the expected result @ Rahul Tailwal

Comment: If you understand what i said then you should vote my answer. As now you know what wrong you were doing.

Answer (score 0):

do something like:

```
if ( isset( $_POST['keyword'] ) ) { ... }
```

Comment: Don't be so offensive :)